# MacBook Pro: Some keys not working (correctly) anymore

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

On my brother's MacBook Pro, suddenly the Enter, right shift, and right alt keys do not work properly anymore. It works with an external keyboard, though. PRAM/SMC reset did not help. Strangely, at least the shift and alt keys seem to at least work mechanically: When I press shift and a key, both inputs are completely ignored. When I press e.g. shift/alt/a, the correct special character is printed. So at least shift/alt seem to work, but only in some circumstances.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: How old is the MBP, and any accidental spills?

Comment: The MPB is from April 2011, and according to my brother no spills have ocurred.

Comment: Get a dusk can, a pressure can in computer store. Then blast all dirt that might sit under the keys.

Comment: We already removed the keys from the keyboard and cleaned the area underneath, but it was not dirty/dusty.

Comment: I could not know that since you did not mention in your question. It would be helpful to name your repair efforts.Like did you unplug and plug the keyboard cable?

Comment: Does it work as virtual keyboard ? on the screen keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Working correctly with an external keyboard is a good indicator that the internal keyboard is damaged and needs repair or replacement.

Comment: I would not be so harsh with a 2011 keyboard.

Comment: @buscar It's just that I have seen users report this problem dozens of times, and when an external keyboard works right, damage to the internal one is almost always the answer, regardless of age or absence of spills, etc.  Sometimes they go bad electrically for no obvious reason.